# Unset from string-query issue

Tags: php, array-unset

```
<?php
    $so = array('marke'=> $_GET["marke"],
                  'farbe'=> $_GET["farbe"],
                  'sort'=> $_GET["sort"]);

    $parameter = http_build_query($so);

    $unsetfarbe = unset($parameter['farbe']);

?>
```

It causes server error, what is wrong here?

Comment: `unset` doesn't return anything; parsing your code as-is generates an 'unexpected unset` error. Removing the assignment of `$unsetfarbe` means that it parses, though it still might not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$parameter` is not an array. It is a string that your created using `http_build_query()`. So you're trying to access a variable that doesn't exist (`$parameter['farbe']`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code should be doing this:

```
<?php
    $so = array('marke'=> $_GET["marke"],
                  'farbe'=> $_GET["farbe"],
                  'sort'=> $_GET["sort"]);

    unset($so['farbe']);
    $parameter = http_build_query($so);

?>
```